# How to keep UIViewController's Navigation bar on top avoiding RootViewController(UIScrollerView)'s Navigation bar?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios6

In my app I am loading a view controller in a scrollview.The scrollview has a navigation bar. For this reason the view controllers loading on it shows double navigation bar with it's own. How to prevent it?

[image]

If i hide scrollview's navigation bar then the top position remain's blank.Can i fit view controller's navigation bar in place of scrollview navigation bar??

[image]

Always welcome for any kind of help.

Comment: try to start you scroll view position from top of the view.

Comment: I tried to resize my view controller after removing the scrollview navigation controller from superView,as i need to make ViewController full screen.

    CGRect cgRect;
    cgRect.origin.x=0;
    cgRect.origin.y=0;
    cgRect.size.height=460;
    cgRect.size.width=320;
    self.view.frame= cgRect;
    [self loadView];
still same.top position is blank!

Comment: how are you loading the view controller into scroll view?

Comment: if (controller.view.superview == nil) {
        CGRect frame = self.scrollView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        controller.view.frame = frame;
        [self.scrollView addSubview:controller.view];
work like this to add view controller in scrollView

Answer (score 0):

Hide Your `RootviewController` navigation bar and increase `contentoffset` of `scrollview` as per your requirement.

Comment: [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(320 ,480) animated:TRUE]; is not working in UIScrollViewDelegate method.

Answer (score 0):

```
[ViewController.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```